# Using jQuery > 1.7.2 and mooTools core issue "i is not a function" Array.foreach

Tags: jquery, mootools

got a problem using jQuery 1.7.2 and higher with the mootools core 1.4.5.

Got always this error message in firebug:

> TypeError: i is not a function     ...n
>   this){x.call(y,this[w],w,this);}}},each:function(i,v){**Array.forEach**(this,i,v)

Got someone an idea how i can solve this problem?

THX!

Comment: Is that error coming from within one of the referenced libraries, or is that coming from your own code?

Comment: Please show your code and what line and what library gives that error. `Array.forEach` is native JavaScript since ES5...

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery library and virtually all of its plugins are contained within the jQuery namespace. As a general rule, global objects are stored inside the jQuery namespace as well, so you shouldn't get a clash between jQuery and any other library (like `prototype.js`, `MooTools`, or `YUI`).

That said, there is one caveat: **by default**, jQuery uses `$` as a shortcut for `jQuery`. Thus, if you are using another JavaScript library that uses the `$` variable, you can run into conflicts with jQuery. In order to avoid these conflicts, you need to put jQuery in **no-conflict mode** immediately after it is loaded onto the page and before you attempt to use jQuery in your page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

Read more [here](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/).

Comment: But then what about mootools?